# c* schema - denormalization vs materialized view

Tags: cassandra

Schema is:

```
col0 int,
col1 text,
col2 text,
stamp timestamp,
somemap map<text, int>
```

I want to query for `somemap`
- using col0, col1 and a range of stamp
- using col0, col1, col2 and a range of stamp

I need every value of `somemap` for distinct col0, col1, col2, stamp to be present for either query (IE for the first query I want all the values of col2 to be there)

I've tried various combinations of columns for **primary key** but I can't find one that permits both types of queries.

I can denormalize this and create both types of tables:
- primary key ((col0, col1), stamp, col2)
- primary key ((col0, col1), col2, stamp)

What Im hoping for is a way to use a **materialized view** to accomplish this.